# tmux status line width with unicode characters

Tags: tmux

I'm running `tmux 3.1b` on `RHEL 7.9`.

The following `.tmux.conf` leads to an expected status line:

```
$ cat .tmux.conf
set -g status-left "test"
```

[image: correct status line]

However, if I put a full-with unicode character in the status line:

```
$ cat .tmux.conf
set -g status-left " test"
```

[image: incorrect status line]

The status line seems to be rendered with inappropriate width in the presence of full-width characters, resulting in an overflow onto the next line. Every time `tmux` refreshes the line, it adds another new line. Anyone have an idea why this might be happening or how to tell `tmux` to pad the status line less? I did some digging and there are some people complaining of the wrong width for unicode characters in `tmux`, but I'm not confident that's the problem here.

I'm using `mintty 3.4.4` fwiw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to a disagreement between libc, terminal and font about character width. Try building tmux with utf8proc or try a different terminal or font.

Comment: Fresh install of `tmux` with `./configure --enable-utf8proc` did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: For those who get `configure: error: "utf8proc not found"`, you need to install `libutf8proc-dev`.